# (iphone) how can I tell I need a 3.0 + iOS installed device when looking at apple doc?

Tags: iphone, ios, version

I've seen iphone related open source library which says something like,

"You need 4.0+ iOS build environment but the code will run on 3.0+ iOS device."

I wonder how those two requirements can differ and how can I tell a minimum 'device' iOS version which a certain api would need.

For instance I want to use UIGestureRecognizer but the apple doc says it's 3.2+, but I want my app run on 3.12+.

Is there a difference between build os requirement and device os requirement to run an app?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a difference. You can use a higher version of iOS to build an app targeted for a lower version of iOS (they are build settings, Base SDK & iOS Deployment Target respectively).

An example would be using the 4.0 iOS as your base sdk but setting your iOS Deployment Target to iOS 3.0, in this case if the compiler came across a function that is not supported for all iOS versions from 3.0 to 4.0 it will take that into account (i think its called weak linking).

If you know that there is a function that isn't going to work on versions of iOS that you want to support you can use something like this to stop that code executing:

```
    if ( [anObject respondsToSelector:@selector(myFunctionForiOS4)] ) {
        [anObject myFunctionForiOS4];
    } else {
        [anObject myFunctionForiOS3];
    }
```

Comment: thanks, so when apple doc says 3.2+, the api will run on target device  3.2+ right? Wonder why some open source project says 3.2+ for device and 4.0+ for build. I guess some of their functionality won't run on less than 4.0 device?

Comment: They say 3.2+ for device and 4.0+ for build because Apple wants you to build with the latest SDK. So the open source project saying 4.0+ for build is really just saying that they build with 4.0+ and don't have any issues. Some projects built for 2.x or 3.x do run into issues when building for 4.x